# What do I need to put in the class part of my section tag?

Tags: javascript, html, css, google-books-api

I'm using eclipse to write an html page that uses a JavaScript function that connects to the google BookAPI. I based mine off of the one I found here (https://codepen.io/mkokes/pen/KqvZNY). I changed it slightly so that instead of using an ISBN number it uses the name of the book and the author to find the cover page.

I get a result on the book but its the wrong one (always the same one so I assume its a problem when I call the script).

My code to call and use the script looks like this:

```
<section class="styles" data-title="Animal Farm" data-author="George Orwell">
  
  <img src="" alt="" class="thumbnail" />  
  
  <header>
    <h3 class="title"></h3>
    <h4 class="author"></h4>
  </header>
  
</section>
```

The styles is the css that I use to format the page. Is that the right thing to put there or am I completely wrong?

My JavaScript is as follows:

```
var title = $('.book').data('title');
var author = $('.book').data('author');

$.ajax({
  dataType: 'json',
  url: 'https://www.googleapis.com/books/v1/volumes?q=' + title + '+inauthor:' + author + '&orderBy=relevance&maxResults=1',
  success: handleResponse
});

function handleResponse( response ) {
  $.each( response.items, function( i, item ) {
    
    var title    = item.volumeInfo.title,
        author   = item.volumeInfo.authors[0],        
        thumb    = item.volumeInfo.imageLinks.thumbnail;
    
    $('.title').text( title );
    $('.author').text( author );
    $('.thumbnail').attr('src', thumb);
  });
}
```

If anyone has any suggestions I'd really appreciate it. Would be great to finally get this working.

Comment: in your JS you are looking for an element with class book to get its data-attribute but you have no elements with class book in your html

Answer (score 0):

I think you are a bit mixed up on CSS classes.  Think of it this way:

The `id` attribute in HTML is a unique identifier, no other element on the page can use that same ID. There's only one.  Exmaple `<div id="navigation">`

The `class` attribute in HTML can contain multiple classes. A "class" is basically just another identifier, but the page can contain multiples of these.  A good example of this for your code would be `.book` however it looks as if your HTML doesn't actually use that class anywhere.  Perhaps this should be: `<section class='book'`

You currently have `class="styles"` on that, and I think that's where you're mixed up, unless you actually have a CSS selector for `.styles` somewhere, and if you did you should rename that to something that's more descriptive.

Also, both the `id` and `class` attributes can be used in CSS and in JS for selecting elements.

I've re-written your code a bit and added some styles for an example.

```js
var books = $('.book'); //This will select all of the .book elements and return an array

//Now we can loop through each selected .book element: https://api.jquery.com/each/
books.each(function(){
  var thisBook = $(this);
  var title = thisBook.data('title');
  var author = thisBook.data('author');

  $.ajax({
    dataType: 'json',
    url: 'https://www.googleapis.com/books/v1/volumes?q=' + title + '+inauthor:' + author + '&orderBy=relevance&maxResults=1',
    success: function(response){
      handleResponse(thisBook, response);
    }
  });
});

function handleResponse( thisBook, response ) {
  $.each( response.items, function( i, item ) {
    
    var title    = item.volumeInfo.title,
        author   = item.volumeInfo.authors[0],        
        thumb    = item.volumeInfo.imageLinks.thumbnail;
    
    thisBook.find('.title').text( title );
    thisBook.find('.author').text( author );
    thisBook.find('.thumbnail').attr('src', thumb);
  });
}
```

```css
.book {
  border: 1px solid #333;
  padding: 5px;
  margin-bottom: 10px;
}

.book .thumbnail {
  max-height: 200px;
  margin-right: 10px;
  float: left;
}

.book header {
  background: #CCC;
  
}

.book .title{
  margin-top: 0;
}

.book author {

}

.clear {
  clear: both;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<section class="book" data-title="Animal Farm" data-author="George Orwell">
  
  <img src="" alt="" class="thumbnail" />  
  
  <header>
    <h3 class="title"></h3>
    <h4 class="author"></h4>
  </header>
  
  <div class='clear'></div>
</section>

<section class="book" data-title="The Great Gatsby" data-author="F. Scott Fitzgerald">
  
  <img src="" alt="" class="thumbnail" />  
  
  <header>
    <h3 class="title"></h3>
    <h4 class="author"></h4>
  </header>
  
  <div class='clear'></div>
</section>

<section class="book" data-title="Moby Dick" data-author="Herman Melville">
  
  <img src="" alt="" class="thumbnail" />  
  
  <header>
    <h3 class="title"></h3>
    <h4 class="author"></h4>
  </header>
  
  <div class='clear'></div>
</section>
```

Comment: In the code I based mine off, class='media book showcase' but unless I've missed something I cant find what that's actually referencing. I tried your suggestion of putting book in the class attribute but that didn't seem to change anything.

Comment: @Icarus101, look for `.media`, `.book`, `.showcase` in the original CSS. You didn't include your CSS, but unless you have defined styles for `.styles{your styles here}`, it won't do anything.

Comment: @FiniteLooper Hi, first off, thanks for the answer. Didnt think anyone would literally rewrite my code. But when I try the code in my program I dont end up with what the code snippet does. For some reason I only get the 3 sections with nothing in them. Any idea what could be causing this?

Comment: It’s hard to say just based on your description. Do you have errors in your console? If you are running this locally, like just files on your computer and not in a local dev server, that might be the issue.

Answer (score 0):

```
<section class="styles" data-title="Animal Farm" data-author="George Orwell">
```

should be

```
<section class="styles book" data-title="Animal Farm" data-author="George Orwell">
```

so that you can then look for the data attributes in your js with:

```
var title = $('.book').data('title');
var author = $('.book').data('author');
```

I don't know what you use `styles` class for but you can keep it even in case it is unused.

When you do `$('.book').` in jquery you are looking for all the items on your page with the class book. When you do `$('#book').` you look for the objcet with the id book (ids are unique in a page).
In your html you will probably have many different classes and ids that are not related (or may be not related) to any css rule but used only for js purposes